# How to make my application auto-start after system bootup, rpm, Fedora 10

Tags: fedora, rpm

I am using Fedora 10 linux. I have created RPM file for my software. It works fine. But it doesnot start automatically when I boot up my computer. Is there anything that I have to do during creation of RPM file or .desktop file. How my application will automatically restarts after installation.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Put the .desktop file in the following folder in Fedora linux to start the application during startup

/etc/xdg/autostart

If we want to start the application before my desktop starts (means to start during driver load) then put the shell script file in the below path

/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d directory
```

Comment: Your response also helped me alot. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 2):

My Operating system: Fedora release 8 , today I had a same situation(Need to start SVNserver at system start-up. I achieved the same using below steps , it may be useful for you

**Step1.**
Created below script file "svn_start_script.sh" in "/etc/init.d"

```
#!/bin/bash
svnserve -d
```

Remember : make the file executable.

**Step2.**
Created a sybmolic link in run-level directory. In my case it is /etc/rc.d/rc5.d ( run level 5)

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/svn_start_script.sh /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/S50svn_start_script.sh
```

IMP : link file name should start with 'S50' , The S50 is to tell the
system to start the script when it boots up,
(You can see 'S50bluetooth' is there to start Bluetooth services at
start-up)

You May refer this [site](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/red-hat-fedora-linux/24951-start-script-boot.html) for further reading

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write an initscript and install it into /etc/init.d, and symlink it into the rc.3 and rc.5 directories (and whatever other runlevels you want). If you pattern your initscript after some of the ones already on your system, you can create these symlinks with the chkconfig program.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try adding your script in **/etc/rc.local** or **/etc/init.d/rc.local**

UBUNTU USER